# How to pass response data from ajax succes to callback function?

Tags: jquery

```
(function($)
{

    $.fn.makeAjaxPostCall = function(options)
        {
            var settings = $.extend( true,{}, $.fn.makeAjaxPostCall.defaults, options );
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url:  settings.url,
                data:   settings.data,
                success: function(data, textStatus, xhr){
                    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 0) {

                        alert('Network Error');
                    }
                    else {alert(data);
                        settings.callback.call(data);
                    }
                },
                error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    if (textStatus !== null) {
                        alert("error: " + textStatus);
                    } else if (errorThrown !== null) {
                        alert("exception: " + errorThrown.message);
                    }
                    else {
                        alert ("error");
                    }
                }
            });
        };
        $.fn.makeAjaxPostCall.defaults = {
            type : 'POST',
            url : '',
            data : {},
            obj : $(document),
            callback : function(data){}
        };

})(jQuery);
```

This is my ajax function. And I am calling this function as

```
$(document).makeAjaxPostCall({
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'UpdateNodeStatus',
    data : {
        workshopid : 1,
        userid : 1001,
        level : 5,
        nodeid : 10,
        resolutionid : 1
    },
    callback : function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

after post happened I am returning 'true' from servlet.

```
response.setContentType("text");
    PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
    pw.print(true);
```

I am getting data as 'true' in 'success', but as 'undefined' in callback.

How do I pass 'data' from 'success' to 'callback' function to use it in there?

Comment: Should it not just be `settings.callback(data);`?

Comment: @Archer - using `call()` should work as well, but all of this looks like just jumping through a lot of hoops to create a new ajax function that does just about the same as the one already available in jQuery ?

Comment: @adeneo I totally agree.  Why extend something that works perfectly anyway?

Comment: @adeneo - yes I agree, but I don't want to write success and failure code every time I make ajax call,nearly 30 to 40 times in my application in different pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can direclty call the callback function without .call like following

```
settings.callback(data);
```

Or If you want to use the `.call` then send `this` as first argument to `.call`.

```
if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 0) {
   alert('Network Error');
}
else {
    alert(data);
    settings.callback.call(this, data);
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call